# How to make stylelint prevent an empty line after the last brace in a nested block?

Tags: css, stylelint

Which configuration settings are required to get this output:

```
.namespace {
   .title {}

   .item {}
}
```

I found a configuration for the empty line between the blocks, but nothing about preventing the last empty line in a nested block.

```
.namespace {
   .title {}
   --- rule-nested-empty-line-before ---
   .item {}
   --- But this empty line should throw a warning ---
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`block-closing-brace-empty-line-before`](http://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-closing-brace-empty-line-before/) rule was added in `stylelint@7.1`. You can disallow or allow an empty line before the closing brace of a block using this rule.

As you wish to disallow an empty line, you should use the `"never"` primary option e.g.

```
"block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": "never"
```

This will enforce the following code style:

```
.namespace {
  .item {}
}
```

Comment: This rule is deprecated.